# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden, localhost:12401

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I am trying to run the [Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-OOXML-EmbedAddin) solution. I have downloaded the repository and added the references according to the documentation. When I start the application using <kbd>F5</kbd>, the browser opens, but I receive the error shown below.

[image: Error in browser]

When executing the command suggested by the error page, I receive an error as well.

```
C:\Program Files\IIS>appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true
```

> 'appcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I also tried adding the following lines to the `Web.config` of the project, but it still did not work.

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, navigate to `Properties > Web` of your solution. From there, change the *Start Action* to load a *Specific Page* and select `Home.aspx`.

[image: Specific Page Setting]